# Pronunciation of Repo

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce *repo* when it means *repository*?

Is it `ˈɹiːpoʊ` or `ˈɹepoʊ`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is pronounced [ˈɹiːpoʊ] by everyone I know.